# How to efficiently clean linebreak in entire dataset R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

Line break is always the first target to prevent new line splitted in new row when perform "import text file" in Excel.Or export to other application with csv file importing.
(The solution might be able to apply in clean another special mark in dataset.
)

## Goal clean all line break into space of entire dataset

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,gsub("\\n","",.SD))]
```

## Problems

R freezed after applying the script with +50 cols & +3 million rows

What's wrong with the lapply approach above?And what is the preferred approach to clean certain things on entire table ?

Comment: Can you try `dt[,lapply(.SD,gsub, pattern = "\n", replacement = "")]` ? Also it is easier to help if we have a reproducible example.

Comment: Do you have any idea of apply gsub of this approach : for (j in cols) set(dt, j = j, value = -dt[[j]])
 from @Akrun comment ?

Comment: be sure to use fixed=TRUE if your regex doesn't require pattern matching

Comment: thanks for the answers please post your answer then i can send "accepted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chinsoon12 is basically it -- use `set` for low-overhead by-reference column overwrite; just add `fixed=TRUE` to make the regex faster too:

```
for (jj in seq_len(ncol(dt))) set(dt, , jj, gsub('\n', '', dt[[jj]], fixed = TRUE))
```

BTW, `\\n` is different from `\n`. `\n` is the literal newline character, `\\n` is the string `"\n"`, i.e., a backslash followed by `n`. You can see the difference thus:

```
cat('hey\nyou')
# hey
# you
cat('hey\\nyou')
# hey\nyou
```